# How do I make my LESS variables available for all CSS files in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, asset-pipeline, less

#### What I have:

In Rails 3.2.2, I have the following stylesheets:

```
    app/assets/stylesheets
    |
    |-- application.css
    |-- bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less
    |
    |-- annotations.css.less
    |-- maps.css.less.erb
    `-- users.css.less.erb
```

The two first ones are more or less system-default. The other ones are where I define my custom styles.

So, `application.css`, as usual, includes all the other files:

```
*= require_self
*= require_tree .
```

And `bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less`, of course, includes Twitter Bootstrap as well as some other custom defined LESS variables.

```
@import "twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap";
@import "twitter/bootstrap/responsive";
// other stuff
@brown_text: #332820;
```

---

#### What doesn't work:

Now, in `annotations.css.less`, I'd like to use `@brown_text`, but it gives me:

> `variable @brown_text is undefined`

I figure this is because there's no reference from `annotations.css.less` to the "master" file where the variable would be defined. And it seems that `annotations.css.less` is compiled first – note that I'm currently in development environment.

So, how can I use my custom LESS variables then, and make them available in other stylesheet files? My current "fix" is to just move all my custom styles into `bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less.erb`, which doesn't seem very clean at all.

#### What *also* doesn't work:

Just `import`ing the LESS files isn't possible, because they use Rails' asset path helpers. And importing an ERB file is also not possible, since the `@import` statement won't find the file, because it expects a `.less` suffix.

Answer (score 8):

You don't need to use ERB for asset path helpers – they're actually baked into the less-rails gem, which you can reference here: https://github.com/metaskills/less-rails/#helpers

You should be able to just use asset-path or asset-url anywhere you've used ERB to refer to the assets pipeline.

Given this, the best way to go would be to:

1. Convert `application.css` to `application.css.less`
2. Delete all the Sprockets directives
3. `@import` each individual file in the directory.
4. Remove the .erb extension from any files that have it, and change ERB asset helpers to less-rails asset helpers.
5. Make sure `annotations.css.less` is imported *after* `bootstrap_and_overrides` – this is why it's usually not a good idea to use `require_tree .`, since you can't control the order in which the files are loaded. The way you have it now, annotations.css.less would be loaded before bootstrap_and_overrides – before the variable you want to use even exists.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Just for clarification – what are "Sprockets directives"?

Comment: Sprockets directives are what Rails (really a gem that Rails depends on, which is called sprockets) uses to load JS / CSS files to compile into one file. So in your code example above the directives are:

    `*= require_self` and 
    `*= require_tree .`

Directives start with `*=` for CSS and `//=` for JS. With the LESS @import commands, you don't need the directives anymore, since you're including your stylesheets with LESS instead. The benefit of using LESS for this is that you still have access to your variables; using the directives, you don't.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Still got much to learn about the asset pipeline and all that stuff. I'll try and fix that tomorrow. Thanks in the meantime!

Answer (score 1):

The way twitter-bootstrap-rails is compiling things, you will need to import your other LESS stylesheets into the overrides file. So for an additional file, `annotations.less`:

```
@import "twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap";
@import "twitter/bootstrap/responsive";

//other LESS styles
@import "annotations"
```

For more, look into less-rails, which this gem uses underneath.

Comment: I use the `less-rails` gem already, but how about importing `maps.css.less.erb` – how would I get correct asset paths there? I use `erb` because I need the paths to some image assets, et cetera.

Comment: It should still work. Sprockets processes the file from right to left, so ERB is evaluated first, then LESS and then CSS.

Comment: Oh, and you will want to name the files *.less instead of *.css.less. Sorry.

Comment: Okay, so for a simple case this works, but I can't import a `less.erb` file anymore. `@import "foo"` will say it can't find `foo.less`, because it's actually `foo.less.erb`. And importing `foo.less.erb` will try to import `foo.less.erb.less` …

Comment: It seems like it's an either or situation. Sprockets works one file at a time so variables can't cross streams and using LESS imports won't trigger Sprockets.